# Add property to IClientMessageInspector

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-client

This is a Visual Studio 2010 C# app with the Service Reference receiving SOAP envelopes. The application works fine and has been running nightly for several months in an automated process to pull data from the service and write it to a db. Because it runs at night and is automated, the UI is very slim.

I want to add a textbox to the form so I can see the response on occasion for debugging purposes. I occasionally get things in the log that don't make sense. The MessageInspector class has an AfterReceiveReply that outputs the response to the console window, which is fine during development, but I want to have it also output to the UI. I created a public property but I can't seem to get the response to populate properly.

```
public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
    private string ThisResponse;
    public string GlobalResponse
    {
        get
        {
            return ThisResponse;
        }
        set
        {
            ThisResponse = value;
        }
    }
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SOAP Response: {0}", reply.ToString());
        ThisResponse = reply.ToString();
    }
```

In the form I call what is below and GlobalResponse is null.

```
MyMessageInspector Output = new MyMessageInspector();
txtResponse.Text = Output.GlobalResponse;
```

Comment: Need more code from the ASP.NET portion to get an idea of how you're getting data from the Console app to the web app.

Comment: Windows app not ASP.net. The line "Console.WriteLine("SOAP Response: {0}", reply.ToString());" gets the envelope to the console window. "ThisResponse = reply.ToString();" populates the private member for the property.

Answer (score 0):

I had declared the property incorrectly. It should have been

static string ThisResponse;

public static string GlobalResponse {

}

Then I reference it like this...

txtResponse.Text = MyMessageInspector.GlobalResponse;

Greg